# Trouble with google maps api v3 polyline and markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Well im making this GPS tracking app , the gps are constantly sending data to a database so all i need to do i fetch that data and use the api, the app is suposed to draw the route of one given car id. this is my code

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($losDatos);$i++)
{
if($losDatos[$i+1]['latitud']<>$losDatos[$i]['latitud'] || $losDatos[$i+1]['longitud']<>$losDatos[$i]['longitud'])
{
$script.="latArray.push(".$losDatos[$i]['latitud'].");";
$script.="lngArray.push(".$losDatos[$i]['longitud'].");";
$script.="codigos.push(".$losDatos[$i]['codigo'].");";
$script.="fechas.push('".$losDatos[$i]['fecha']."');";
$script.="velocidades.push(".$losDatos[$i]['velocidad'].");";
}
}
```

once ive filled all the array i call a function of mine called route. all the parameters in this function are arrays

```
 route(latArray,lngArray,codigos,fechas,velocidades);


function route(lats,lngs,codigos,fechas,vs,weight)
{
var pointsArray=[];
//make a new point for each lat,lng 
for(i=0;i<latArray.length;i++)
    {
    pointsArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i],lngs[i]));

    //this next function adds a marker and sets an infowindow with code,date and speed for each one.
    addMarker(lats[i],lngs[i],codigos[i],fechas[i],vs[i]);
    }

//then I send my pointsArray to the polyline 
var ruta = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: pointsArray,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: weight});

ruta.setMap(map);
}
```

the trouble is that my polyline points and the marker points do not match they are like 30 pixels away from each other when they are supposed to be in the same location

Comment: is it 30px no matter what zoom level, or are the points further away when you're zoomed in than zoomed out?

Comment: no matter the zoom level theyre always beside the line!

Comment: ok, well that means that you've got a problem with how you're placing them (ie, the geographic coords are probably fine). Could it be a css issue?

Comment: so far im not using css ill leave that to the very last! so i dont think is css issue , other guy who was working here did the same thing i am doing but he used api v2 im using api v3 could this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

well problem solved i had a problem with the image size i was originally using thin

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos, 
            map: map,
                icon:'img/bluedot.png' 
});
```

but it seemed i needed to be more specific so i did this

```
var icon=new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/bluedot.png',new google.maps.Size(6,6),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(0,1));

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos, 
                map: map,
                        icon:icon 
    });
```